# xcode: How to hide this warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I imported ElementParser to my project in order to parse an html string. But xcode reports a warning at the following code:

```
if ([connectionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connection:didFailWithError:)])
    [connectionDelegate connection:connection didFailWithError: error]; // Warning at this line
```

Since the first line has a check, the second must be safe at runtime.

I really don't like warnings to exist in my project. So I wonder if there is anyway to hide this warning?

Comment: Is it possible to use protocols? If `connectionDelegate` is typed correctly (as conforming to the right protocols) and the `connection:didFailWithError:` method is optional within that protocol, then the above should not produce a warning.

Comment: What type is `connectionDelegate`? `id<NSURLConnectionDelegate`>?  `id<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`>? Something else?

Comment: Cause the code is from githut, not written by myself, I don't want to modify any line, or modify as less as possible lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the object to `id` first.

```
if ([connectionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connection:didFailWithError:)])
    [(id)connectionDelegate connection:connection didFailWithError: error];
```

Or, better yet, as @Rob suggests, for the @interface declaration of your connectionDelegate's class, add the following

```
@interface MyConnectDelegateClass : id<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

Comment: Or better, define `connectionDelegate` right in the first place.

Comment: @Rob, agreed! I only use the `id` cast for limited circumstances.